# How to Change Language for Admin Panel in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, admin-panel, language

In General, I want a shop frontend default language that differs from the admin default language, in the easiest way.

I try

- to log in admin panel and navigate to System > All Users.
- multiple admin users, click on one of them for which you would like
  to change the default language.
- Interface Locale field and click

is that the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Step-By-Step Process to Change Language For Admin Panel in Magento 2

Please follow the below steps to learn how to change the default language for the admin panel in your Magento 2 store.

### Step – 1

First of all, log in to your admin panel and navigate to **System > All Users**.

[image]

### Step – 2

If you have multiple admin users, you need to click on one of them for which you would like to change the default language.

[image]

### Step – 3

After that, select your desired language in the **Interface Locale** field and click on the **Save User** button user to change the default language for the admin panel in your Magento 2 store.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but easy way to find out is to make the test in your sandbox env

Create an admin in command line  (default language is english there)

```
bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user='userTest' --admin-password='test123' --admin-email='test@test.fr' --admin-firstname='user' --admin-lastname='test'
```

With your current admin, do your language modification

Then connect to the newt created admin userTest and see if the language applies.

Though, you have to be aware that you will need to deploy static for the backend language too.

From my experience when salers have a one language store in front side, they tend to only deploy their website in that language and use the same language for the backend. But if you provide a different language for backend (english for example) then you will have to deploy en_US too.